# PDO emulate off, binding same value multiple times

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have the following bit of code in PHP7. I'm using PDO to connect to MySQL.

With PDO prepared statements emulation on, this code works successful:

```
$query = $db_con->prepare('SELECT * FROM matches WHERE matches.home_team_id=:team_id OR matches.away_team_id=:team_id');
$query->bindValue(':team_id', $team_id, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query->execute();
return $query->fetchAll();
```

But with true PDO prepared statements (emulation off), the previous code gives an error that not enough values were bound. I'm forced to do the following:

```
$query = $db_con->prepare('SELECT * FROM matches WHERE matches.home_team_id=:team_id OR matches.away_team_id=:team_id2');
$query->bindValue(':team_id', $team_id, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query->bindValue(':team_id2', $team_id, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query->execute();
return $query->fetchAll();
```

This works, but is there any way I don't have to declare the same variable twice with true prepared statements? I have a lot of these queries, and would like to replace them all to use true prepared statements.

As someone asked in the comments: why do I want emulation off? I didn't really have a preference, but now it seems that true prepared statements are more strict than emulated statements. Is my understanding correct that is is better to develop with true prepared statements to guarantee it will work with both settings?

Comment: There is not way to get around this that I know of. Why don't you want to use emulation?

Comment: I didn't have a reason before, but now that I'm presented with this problem, I do: compatibility with both settings. As you can see from my question, changing the setting broke my code. The code for true prepared statements works with both settings.

Comment: The placeholder name must be unique. Remember, for mysql then all the names become '?' as placeholders. i.e. `:team_id1` and `:team_id2`. Whatever the reason it doesn't work if you use the same placeholder name. Emulate mode is different as PDO builds the query inline with quoted strings. ;-/

Comment: I'm afraid this is a design decision (an questionable one if you ask for my opinion) we have to live with in an otherwise quite reasonable API. It's possible to overcome it by writing a custom layer on top of PDO that rewrites queries and parameters but you need to implement a SQL parser and that's far from being trivial.

Answer (score 1):

There is a way by change the query

```
$query=$db_con->prepare('SELECT*FROM matches WHERE :team_id in(home_team_id,away_team_id)');
$query->bindValue(':team_id', $team_id, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query->execute();
```

This may not desirable, but it declare variable at once for case.

Hope this helpful.

Comment: Did you try this with emulated statements OFF?

Comment: Still doubting after your edit. Why would this code be a solution if it doesn't work with emulation off? Why should I put a single variable in an array? Can you explain what your code does or why it's better than the code in the question? I'm not looking to break down your answer, I'm trying to understand why you think it's a solution. I appreciate your efforts so far :)

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution is to use a counter. In that way you can keep `emulation off` and still bind the same value multiple times without the need to count how many times you've used it, or renumber when you change the query.

```
$count=0;
$query = $db_con->prepare(
    'SELECT * FROM matches WHERE 
    matches.home_team_id=:team_id'.(++$count).' OR 
    matches.away_team_id=:team_id'.(++$count)
    );
for($i=1; $i<($count+1) ;++$i){
    $query->bindValue(':team_id'.$i, $team_id, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    }
$query->execute();
return $query->fetchAll();
```